# SQL command equivalent to pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-restore

Is there any SQL command equivalent to `pg_restore`?  Although I can connect to a PostgreSQL database (on AWS RDS) using `psycopg2` on Python, but don’t have permission to install any binary packages like `pg_restore`.  How can I restore a dump made with `pg_dump` without `pg_restore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent SQL command as of now (PostgreSQL 9.3).

Answer (score 1):

From the [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) manpage:

> pg_restore can operate in two modes. If a database name is specified,
>   pg_restore connects to that database and restores archive contents
>   directly into the database. Otherwise, a script containing the SQL
>   commands necessary to rebuild the database is created and written to a
>   file or standard output.

So, you can use pg_restore to create a series of SQL commands which you can then load into your database.

The [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html) implies you can load that SQL file using psql.

Note that the very same page provides detailed instructions on creating a dump using pg_dump 
which is already in SQL form. If you do that then you don't need to use pg_restore at all.